# python regex with fasta headers

Tags: python, regex

I am having some trouble with regexs in python. How would i go about capturing everything after the > in this string?

`>4L type=chromosome; loc=6L:1.733034524; ID=4L; length=4534673; release=r2.32; species=Homo;
CCAACATATTGTGCTAATGAGTGCCTCTCGTTCTCTGTCTTATATTACCG
CAAACCCAAAAAGACAATACACGACAGAGAGAGAGAGCAGCGGAGATATT
TAGATTGCCTATTAAATATGATCGCGTATGCGAGAGTAGTGCCAACATAT
TGTGCTCTCTATATAATGACTGCCTCTCATTCTGTCTTATTTTACCGCAA`

Output would be this: 
`4L type=chromosome; loc=6L:1.733034524; ID=4L; length=4534673; release=r2.32; species=Homo;
CCAACATATTGTGCTAATGAGTGCCTCTCGTTCTCTGTCTTATATTACCG
CAAACCCAAAAAGACAATACACGACAGAGAGAGAGAGCAGCGGAGATATT
TAGATTGCCTATTAAATATGATCGCGTATGCGAGAGTAGTGCCAACATAT
TGTGCTCTCTATATAATGACTGCCTCTCATTCTGTCTTATTTTACCGCAA`

Edit: I am hoping to use re.match or re.search

Comment: Try `"(?<=\>).*"`

Answer (score 0):

Because each sequence read is multi-lined (per the FASTA standard), regular expressions are not likely to be the best tool for the job. This is because regex patterns are generally meant for processing files line by line searching for a specific pattern and the header and sequence lines in a FASTA don't generally share such a common format/pattern.

Have you tried looking at a tool purposefully designed for the extraction of FASTA records? Biopython has a [module](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO) specifically for handling FASTA/Q sequences.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need regex for this. Split the string at the ">" and select the second part:

```
text = '>4L type=chromosome; loc=6L:1.733034524; ID=4L; length=4534673; 
release=r2.32; species=Homo;
CCAACATATTGTGCTAATGAGTGCCTCTCGTTCTCTGTCTTATATTACCG
CAAACCCAAAAAGACAATACACGACAGAGAGAGAGAGCAGCGGAGATATT
TAGATTGCCTATTAAATATGATCGCGTATGCGAGAGTAGTGCCAACATAT
TGTGCTCTCTATATAATGACTGCCTCTCATTCTGTCTTATTTTACCGCAA'

test = test.split('>')[1]

print(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

To use a regular expression to extract the information you require (ignoring justifications):

```
import re

text = '''>4L type=chromosome; loc=6L:1.733034524; ID=4L; length=4534673; 
release=r2.32; species=Homo;
CCAACATATTGTGCTAATGAGTGCCTCTCGTTCTCTGTCTTATATTACCG
CAAACCCAAAAAGACAATACACGACAGAGAGAGAGAGCAGCGGAGATATT
TAGATTGCCTATTAAATATGATCGCGTATGCGAGAGTAGTGCCAACATAT
TGTGCTCTCTATATAATGACTGCCTCTCATTCTGTCTTATTTTACCGCAA'''
# need . to match a new line.
result = re.search("\>(.*)", text, flags=re.DOTALL)
if result:
    print(result.groups(1))
```

Which prints the following:

```
('4L type=chromosome; loc=6L:1.733034524; ID=4L; length=4534673; \nrelease=r2.32; species=Homo;\nCCAACATATTGTGCTAATGAGTGCCTCTCGTTCTCTGTCTTATATTACCG\nCAAACCCAAAAAGACAATACACGACAGAGAGAGAGAGCAGCGGAGATATT\nTAGATTGCCTATTAAATATGATCGCGTATGCGAGAGTAGTGCCAACATAT\nTGTGCTCTCTATATAATGACTGCCTCTCATTCTGTCTTATTTTACCGCAA',)
```

So perhaps you'll then need to strip out the newlines, maybe with something ugly like this:

```
result.groups(1)[0].replace("\n","")
```